# Make the checkbox non editable by the user but editable programmatically

Tags: android, checkbox

and I want to restrict the user from changing it. I should be able to change it programmatically but not by the user.  I have tried, editable, clickable out did not work.

How should it be done?

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        android:paddingRight="8dip">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/flight_origin_date"
            style="@style/InputCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/new_order_flight_origin_date"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            app:buttonTint="@color/i6_teal" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please set following two fields to `false` in `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox`

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

Comment: but that also stops me from editing it programatically. I want to just stop the user from changing it but allow the change programatically

Comment: In program, you can set the values to `true`

Comment: Wherever you need to enable it , just enable it from programmatically, and where you want to disable it, just set the both values to `false`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an ImageView instead of checkbox, with two different sources, the first image will be a non-checked checkbox image and the second would be a checked-checkbox image, based on your state you can show either, as in if you want to programmatically check the check-box, just switch to the checked-checkbox image and vice-versa, similarly you can update the variables inside by simply switching image sources.